# C++ error when calling a Delphi function with Extended parameters

Tags: delphi, clang, c++builder, delphi-10.1-berlin, c++builder-10.1-berlin

In a new Win32 project, I have the following Delphi function:

```
procedure SetValue(value1, value2 : Extended);
begin
end;
```

In the same project but from a C++ unit, I call this function:

```
SetValue(10, 40);
```

When I check `value1` when compiling with BCC32C (CLang), I get 1.68132090507504896E-4932, that is not correct.

Compiling with BCC32 (classic), I get 10.

The second parameter is 40 in both cases.

It seems that there is a problem with `Extended` values and the parameter stack loading.

I use RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I did not include the declaration because the hpp is created automatically when compiling. In any case, the declaration is:

```
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE void __fastcall SetValue(System::Extended value1, System::Extended value2);
```

To replicate the project:

1-Create a C++ project in Rad Studio

2-Add a Delphi unit with the above SetValue function

3-From C++ unit, add the hpp header with #include and call SetValue

It is all.

I need to use Extended type. I am using an external Delphi library, so I cannot change the types. The above code is a simplification of the problem. In reality, the problem is calling a function of this library that uses Extended in the parameters. Extended is a native type in Delphi but in C++ it is mapped as long double, 10 bytes (for Win32).

Comment: should you not mark the function as cdecl when calling it from external application ?

Comment: How do you declare the function in your C++ code?

Comment: Stop using `Extended`. It's a bad idea. Use `Double` or `Real` (an alias to `Double`). And you simply have to show the calling convention and your C++ code for us to have a chance. Why can't we have a [mcve]? I ask that on just about half of all questions I ever see. Surely the message is getting though .......

Comment: @JoachimPileborg when a Delphi unit is compiled for C++, the Delphi compiler auto-generates a C++ `.hpp` header file. Hopefully the OP is using that header and not declaring the function manually.

Comment: @GuidoG no, the calling convention does not need to be `cdecl`. And the function is not being called by an external application. Delphi code can be used directly in a C++Builder project.

Comment: BCC32 knows the `Extended` type, but BCC32C (the Clang compiler) probably doesn't. So do what @DavidHeffernan said and stop using `Extended`. Use `Double` and `Single` on the Delphi side and `double` and `float` on the C++ side, respectively.

Comment: @Rudy Clang's long double maps to extended on Intel platforms.

Comment: @David: on Intel 32 bit platforms, I guess. Then I can't explain the problem. Hmmm... I could test it myself.

Comment: @rudy and on 64 bit Intel too. I think clang and gcc do the same here.

Comment: @david: OK. I am currently having trouble even trying this. When called from C++Builder, the Delphi compiler can't find System.dcu although this is the complete RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin and it works fine standalone.

Comment: You probably don't need to use Extended. That would be the easiest way forward. Usually people who think they need Extended are mistaken. But it smells like a bug. Submit a bug report. You can work around it by wrapping the args in a record passed as const. I guess.

Comment: @David: I need to use Extended because it is used in a purchased  Delphi library in many functions. I cannot change the source of this library.

Comment: You can choose to use double in your wrapping of library. Any library that uses extended is almost certainly going to perform poorly. And will map to double on 64 bit anyway. Still I gave you the workaround so you can continue until such a time as you can escape the tyranny of extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an error in the BCC32C compiler. I guess it was not extended properly to handle `Extended` as Delphi needs it.

If you look at the CPU window, then the BCC32 compiler generates:

```
File5.cpp.14: SetVal(10.0L, 40.0L);
00401B8F 6802400000       push $00004002
00401B94 68000000A0       push $a0000000
00401B99 6A00             push $00
00401B9B 6804400000       push $00004004
00401BA0 68000000A0       push $a0000000
00401BA5 6A00             push $00
00401BA7 E80C000000       call Unit12::SetVal(long double,long double)
```

and that is correct. It first pushes `10`, then `40` in `Extended` format. Note that each `Extended` occupies 12 byte on the stack.

But now look at the output for the BCC32C compiler:

```
File5.cpp.14: SetVal(10.0L, 40.0L);
00401B5D 89E0             mov eax,esp
00401B5F D90554F14E00     fld dword ptr [$004ef154]
00401B65 DB38             fstp tbyte ptr [eax]
00401B67 D90558F14E00     fld dword ptr [$004ef158]
00401B6D DB780A           fstp tbyte ptr [eax+$0a]
00401B70 E81F000000       call Unit12::SetVal(long double,long double)
00401B75 83EC18           sub esp,$18
```

It first reads the 32 single precision float `40` and stores it as `Extended` at `[ESP]`. So far, so good. But then it reads in the next 32 bit single precision float `10` (still OK) but then **stores it at `[ESP+$0A]`**, which is clearly wrong (for Delphi)! It should be stored at `[ESP+$0C]`! That is why the **first** value, which is read by the Pascal function at `[ESP+$0C]`, but which is stored by BCC32C at `[ESP+$0A]`, is wrong.

**So this seems to be a bug**. Reported as https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15737

*Note that this is the normal way BCC32C pushes and expects such values. In a C++ function in the same module, i.e. compiled with BCC32C too, this works nicely:*

```
void __fastcall Bla(long double a, long double b)
{
    printf("%Lf %Lf\n", a, b);
}
```

*But Delphi expects a 10 byte `Extended` to occupy 12 bytes on the stack, not 10 bytes as BCC32C does.*

*Weirdly enough, if the function to be called is not a Delphi `__fastcall` function, but a normal C++ (`cdecl`) function, the BCC32C compiler will store the `Extended`s (`long double`s) in `[ESP+$0C]` and `[ESP]` respectively.*

#### Workarounds

As David Heffernan commented, you can pass multiple extendeds in a record. Alternatively, you could pass them as `var` parameters. In both cases, it is not as simple as calling `SetVal(10.0, 40.0);`.

Comment: @David: Wrapping will indeed get the proper alignment.

Comment: @David: Regrettably wrapping is not an option. This library is really large, with  hundreds of classes, many of them derived classes, linked between them, interfaces, etc.. It would be really a huge effort to build a wrapper. I will consider to buy the sources and to replace the Extended type by another type. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the library out of interest?

Comment: I know it is a strectch, but you could write a function, either in Delphi (probably easier) or in C++'s built-in assembler, that properly aligns `Extended` and then calls the function you wanted to call directly. So then you would call it like, say, `CallWith2Extendeds(&Unit12::SetValue, 10.0L, 40.0L);`. instead of `SetValue(10.0L, 40.0L);`.

Comment: Finally I have solved it. Instead of calling functions like f->SetSize(Height, Width) that fail because of Extended alignment, I could use directly properties like f->Height, f->Width. Thank you. You saved my week!.

Comment: @kokokok: That will save you this time, but it remains a bug and others will experience it too. And they can perhaps not use properties. But I am glad you found a workaround for your particular problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not a solution, it is just a workaround for my specific case. I see you added the bug in Embarcadero website and hopefully they fix it in a next version. Thank you